# Using table column headers as variables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone know if I can plug in a cell address (my variable) into tbl_source[ ] or will it only accept column titles, and #header, #all.... etc.

Comment: Hey. Can you give an provide a sample syntax or data? You can use the **INDIRECT** function with a table syntax, however I am not sure that you asked. For example: `=SUM(INDIRECT("Table1["&I5&"]"))`

Comment: You can simply use Cell reference as usually we do with other Cells.        =sum(A2:A5) these cell belongs to TABLE I've created and I got the result. Just try this. =INDEX(MyTab[Value],1,1) check this also.